# trying to create a c program that copy names from text file and store them into a hash table but I keep getting "Segmentation fault"

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, hashtable, cs50

the problem is that when I try to copy the name from "Buffer" to the "Node" using "sprintf"
I always get "segmentation fault" !!.

THE CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

//node declaration:
typedef struct node
{
    char* name[20];
    struct node* link;
}
node;

unsigned int hash(char* buffer ,unsigned int CAPACITY) ;

int main(int argc , string argv[])
{
    //declarations:
    FILE* fp = fopen("us-names.txt" , "a+") ;
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("CANNOT OPEN THE FILE !\n") ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    char buffer[20] ;
    unsigned int key = 0;
    unsigned int CAPACITY = 100 ;
    struct node* temp = NULL ;
    struct node* hashtable[CAPACITY] ;

    //Import name from the FILE & store into buffer:
    fgets(buffer , 20 , fp) ;
    //pass the name into the hash_function and get the key:
    key = hash(buffer , CAPACITY) ;

    //put the name in a node then in it's right place in the hashtable using the key:
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node)) ;
    sprintf(*temp->name , "%s" , buffer) ;
    hashtable[key] = temp ;

    //close the FILE & return 0:
    fclose(fp) ;
    return 0;
}

unsigned int hash(char* buffer , unsigned int CAPACITY)
{
    unsigned int sum = 0 ;
    for(int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0' ;i++)
    {
        sum += buffer[i] ;
    }
    return sum % CAPACITY ;
}
```

when I debug my program it shows me that the problem is at this line :
sprintf(*temp->name , "%s" , buffer) ;

and I've tried too many ways to fix it put all of them didn't work !!

I obviously don't know what to do ,I hope some one can help :(

Comment: Any reason to open the file in `"a+"` mode?

Comment: You probably want `char name[20];` in your node struct.

Comment: Why using `*temp->name` ?

Comment: Why the `node.js` tag? If you meant to add a `node` tag then it's not needed, it's kind of implied by the `hashtable` tag. Please be careful when selecting tags.

Comment: `*temp->name` is the same as `temp->name[0]` which is an uninitalized pointer.

Answer (score 2):

These two lines are problematic, and at the same time mask each others contribution to the issue:

```
char* name[20]; //first member of struct  
//and
sprintf(*temp->name , "%s" , buffer) ;
```

The issue being that both contribute equally to the potential that your code will attempt writing to memory that it does not own, thus invoking [undefined behavior](https://raphlinus.github.io/programming/rust/2018/08/17/undefined-behavior.html), and subsequently your observed seg-fault.
Together, although they will not allow your code to work, will allow a clean compile.  Removing the `*` from either one of them (not both) will result in a warning message during compile.  Removing both will allow a clean compile, and allow the `sprintf()` call to work properly.  Here is why...

This:

```
char* name[20];
```

creates 20 instances of uninitialized pointers to char ( `char *` ).  Attempting to write to any one of them will will result in undefined behavior.

Change it to `char name[20];//removing the *`

At this point, after having removed the asterisk above, the second error is unmasked, and an attempted compile  would generate a warning such as this:

> *"warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'char *'; remove *"*

To address this change:

```
sprintf(*temp->name , "%s" , "some value") ;
```

To:

```
sprintf(temp->name , "%s" , "some value");//removed asterisk
```

Comment: it worked! dude U saved my day , thanks so much

Comment: @MohammedHassan If this helped, you can click the accept check mark to the upper left of this post :)